# Array Out of Bounds Exception when rects are deleted, at random times

Tags: java

```
// in graphics

if (delayTimer == 0 && targetable && bossHP > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                bossShotsX.add(bossX + 115 - 15);
                bossShotsY.add(bossY + 115 - 15);
                bossShotsHitBox.add(DemonBoss.drawDemonBossShotsHitBox(g, 
bossShotsY.get(bossShotsY.size() - 1) + 15, bossShotsX.get(bossShotsX.size() - 1) + 15, bossShotType));
                bossShotsDirection.add((i % 8));
                }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bossShotsX.size(); i++) {

        DemonBoss.drawDemonBossShots(g, bossShotsX.get(i) + 15, bossShotsY.get(i) + 15, bossShotType, bossPhase);

        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(bossX + 114,bossY + 114, 2, 2);       
// in action performed method
Rectangle playerHitBox = new Rectangle (p1X, p1Y, 50, 100);
    Rectangle bossHitBox = new Rectangle(bossX + 50, bossY, 130, 230);

    // boss shoot stuff
            for (int i = 0; i < bossShotsHitBox.size(); i++) {
                int xChange = 0, yChange = 0;
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == N) {
                    yChange = -bossShotSpeed;
                }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == NE) {
                    yChange = -bossShotSpeed;
                    xChange = bossShotSpeed;
                }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == E) {
                    xChange = +bossShotSpeed;
                }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == SE) {
                    yChange = bossShotSpeed;
                    xChange = bossShotSpeed;
                    }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == S) {
                    yChange = bossShotSpeed;
                }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == SW) {
                    yChange = bossShotSpeed;
                    xChange = -bossShotSpeed;
                    }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == W) {
                    xChange = -bossShotSpeed;
                }
                if (bossShotsDirection.get(i) == NW) {
                    yChange = -bossShotSpeed;
                    xChange = -bossShotSpeed;
                }
               bossShotsX.set(i, bossShotsX.get(i) + xChange);
               bossShotsY.set(i, bossShotsY.get(i) + yChange);
               bossShotsHitBox.set(i, new Rectangle(bossShotsX.get(i), bossShotsY.get(i), 30, 30));   

        if (playerHitBox.intersects(bossShotsHitBox.get(i))){
            if (bossShotType == 1) {
            P1_HP -= 30;
            }
            bossShotsHitBox.remove(i);  
            bossShotsX.remove(i);
            bossShotsY.remove(i);
            bossShotsDirection.remove(i);
        }

        if (bossShotsX.get(i)  <= 0 ||
            bossShotsX.get(i)  >= 1000 ||
            bossShotsY.get(i)  <= 0 ||
            bossShotsY.get(i)  >= 1000) {
            bossShotsX.remove(i);
            bossShotsY.remove(i);
            bossShotsHitBox.remove(i);
            bossShotsDirection.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

And N, NE, E, etc. are constants that determine direction. You can probably tell what the arraylists are, and all of them are integers except for bossShotsHitBox, which is a rectangle arraylist.

Methods are just some drawing stuff.

I think this is good, isn't it? It shouldn't freeze if the player collides with rectangles. For example, if I start the game, and rush to sit on top of the boss, it freezes the game since i get shot by 8 bullets at the same time, but also it randomly freezes sometimes as well. Where is the error in my code?

Comment: If you print your exceptions stacktrace you will be able to see where the problem is happening

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh thanks lol, found out it was at the place where I made it so the boss shots cant escape, think it was because if they get deleted too fast but the for loop hasn't updated for the new size yet it'll crash or something like that?